# how to detect stated exe is visible or not in java

Tags: java, process

I am starting installer exe using the following code.

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\PathToExe\\installer.exe","param1","param2").start();
```

Exe is taking some time to get visible so I need to wait until the installer is in visible state.

How can I wait for the installer to visible?

Comment: what do you mean: "visible"?

Comment: Why do you need that information? What would you like to do when the installer is visible?

Comment: @Lino I am trying to write automation so when GUI is in visible state I want to perform some keystrokes

Comment: @Stultuske Process starts in the background but GUI for the installer is being visible after 2-3 minutes